"Invalid provider" when trying to inject InjectionToken in NGXS state class
I am trying to inject an InjectionToken in an NGXS State class. However no matter what I try the state class fails to initialize and Angular throws an Error: Invalid provider error.
I am using Angular 18 in combination with the NGXS 18.
Check this StackBlitz Angular project for a live example of the issue (open your debug console to see the error).
I have the following Angular ApplicationConfig:
export interface CustomerConfig {
  name: string;
}

export const CUSTOMER_CONFIG = new InjectionToken<CustomerConfig>(
  'customer_config'
);

export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideZoneChangeDetection({ eventCoalescing: true }),
    provideRouter(routes),
    provideStore([ZooState]),
    // Note howe we provide the CUSTOMER_CONFIG InjectionToken here
    {
      provide: CUSTOMER_CONFIG,
      useValue: {
        name: 'Alice',
      },
    },
  ],
};

The following ZooState:
export interface ZooStateModel {
  favoriteAnimal: string;
}

export const ZOO_STATE_TOKEN = new StateToken<ZooStateModel>('zoo');

@State<ZooStateModel>({
  name: ZOO_STATE_TOKEN,
  defaults: {
    favoriteAnimal: 'Unicorn',
  },
})
@Injectable()
export class ZooState {
  @Selector()
  static favoriteAnimal(state: ZooStateModel) {
    return state.favoriteAnimal;
  }

  constructor(
    // Note how we try and inject the CustomerConfig here
    @Inject(CUSTOMER_CONFIG) private readonly customerConfig: CustomerConfig
  ) {
    console.log('Welcome to the zoo state!');
  }
}

From what I've seen this only appears when using InjectionTokens. I can inject services just fine.
How can I solve this and inject InjectionTokens into my NGXS state classes?

To my knowledge it looks like a bug. When we use @Inject(CUSTOMER_CONFIG) private readonly customerConfig: CustomerConfig the application fails to load, with the error you have shown. As a temporary workaround. You can define the provide as a string instead 'CUSTOMER_CONFIG', then it seems to work fine.
Feel free to raise a bug on their github repo.
App.config.ts
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideZoneChangeDetection({ eventCoalescing: true }),
    provideRouter(routes),
    provideStore([ZooState]),
    {
      provide: 'CUSTOMER_CONFIG',
      useValue: {
        name: 'Alice',
      },
    },
  ],
};

zoo.state.ts
export class ZooState {
  static favoriteAnimal(age: string) {
    return createSelector([ZooState], (state: ZooStateModel) => {
      return state.favoriteAnimal;
    });
  }

  constructor(
    @Inject('CUSTOMER_CONFIG') private readonly customerConfig: CustomerConfig
  ) {
    console.log('Welcome to the zoo state!');
  }
}

Stackblitz Demo

Hi, thank you for your reply. I will create a bug in their repo.

Took some time but for anyone running into this the Github bug report can be found here.
